C#: Why doesn't the compiler convert this method group to a method?
Why doesn't the commented-out line compile? It seems like the compiler should be able to infer the method signature without any ambiguity.
public class Program {
    static string A(int x) => $"a{x}";
    static string B(int x) => $"b{x}";
    
    public static void Main() {
        var a = A;
        var b = B;
        // Console.WriteLine((true ? A : B)(34)); // this does not work
        Console.WriteLine((true ? a : b)(34)); // this does
    }
}


This is a result of A being an actual method, where as a is a variable with a type, the thing is that, this type is that of a Func<TInput, TResult>. You can see this with Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());. Docs on Func here

Do not use var if you do not know what the type it is or should be, or rather, if you use var, use the functionality of your IDE to CTRL + . and convert it to the proper explicit type
